# Why writing Laravel's route can be differ in Mac & Windows?and which one is correct?

Tags: php, laravel, windows, macos, routes

I currently developing Laravel application, since I use 2 different laptop and OS (Windows & Macbook), I realized that everytime I swicth PC, I have to changes the route in file web.php, just to make my app running well.

Why there is a difference of writing Laravel's route between Windows & Mac OS, can I make the writing just same?so I don't need to modify the script everytime I switched PC.

Here is the working route on Windows :

```
Route::get('/movies', 'MovieController@index');
Route::get('/movies/create', 'MovieController@create');
Route::get('/movies/edit/{id}', 'MovieController@edit');
Route::post('/movies/insert', 'MovieController@store');
Route::post('/movies/update', 'MovieController@update');
Route::get('/movies/delete/{id}', 'MovieController@destroy');
```

And here is the working route on my Macbook :

```
Route::get('/movies', 'App\Http\Controllers\MovieController@index');
Route::get('/movies/create', 'App\Http\Controllers\MovieController@create');
Route::get('/movies/edit/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\MovieController@edit');
Route::post('/movies/insert', 'App\Http\Controllers\MovieController@store');
Route::post('/movies/update', 'App\Http\Controllers\MovieController@update');
Route::get('/movies/delete/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\MovieController@destroy');
```

And this is the error displayed if I tried to run my app with the not worked one :

[image]

Here is another specification that maybe could help you to analyze :

- PHP Version 8.1.10
- Composer Version 2.5.1
- On Windows I use XAMPP
- On Macbook I use Nginx

Is there any things that I need to change or adjust to make my route working well in both Windows and Mac OS?

Please help and please let me know if you need any further information.

Thank you.

Comment: If I had to guess, your class files do not follow PSR-4 naming convention regarding case and you have e.g. `moviecontroller.php` instead of `MovieController.php`. NTFS is case-insensitive and ignores the error, Mac filesystem is case-sensitive and rightfully fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [use](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) your controllers and then reference the controller class in your route.

For example:

```php
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\MovieController;

Route::get('/movies', [MovieController::class, 'index']);
```

This is also how it is done in the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#the-default-route-files).

Comment: Why did it work on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the class first

```php
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\API\Frontend\BlogController;
use App\Http\Controllers\API\Frontend\CategoryController;
use App\Http\Controllers\API\RegisterController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::controller(RegisterController::class)->group(function(){
    Route::post('register', 'register');
    Route::post('login', 'login');
    Route::get('test', 'test');
});
```

it's a demo but if you see closely you will understand this. there are some extension for this to auto-import classes for vs code laravel-blade-snepate something like this or you can search youtube auto import laravel classes in your_code_editor_name.